# How to use keep_after_last in Freemarker template

Tags: freemarker

I have the below code and i want to keep only last string or text e.g. **ABC G56**, so i want to keep only **G56** after space so i am using keep_after_last in freemarker.

```
<td>${value?keep_after_last(" ")}</td>
```

but i am getting errors:

> caused by: freemarker.core.parseexception: error on line 57, column 46, in template .ftl found keep_after_last, expecting one of: date, is_directive, parent, js_string, j_string, replace, uncap_first, float, right_pad, is_transform, number, datetime, node_type, split, is_hash, trim, children, has_content, is_sequence, xml, html, ancestors, new, last, byte, double, left_pad, sort, matches, capitalize, contains, eval, lower_case, size, web_safe, is_date, is_string, word_list, seq_last_index_of, node_namespace, string, keys, values, seq_index_of, chunk, sort_by, is_collection, long, starts_with, substring, index_of, default, root, is_boolean, floor, last_index_of, ceiling, if_exists, c, chop_linebreak, is_macro, rtf, upper_case, length, node_name, is_indexable, groups, reverse, cap_first, is_node, int, url, is_hash_ex, xhtml, ends_with, round, is_enumerable, interpret, is_method, namespace, exists, short, seq_contains, time, first, is_number in .ftl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your FreeMarker version is too old. `?keep_after_last` was added in 2.3.22 (see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_keep_after_last).

If you are not sure which version you are using, you can output it using `${.version}` (see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_specvar.html).

Comment: so, we can't use this now?

Comment: As I said, that depends on the version. See update on how to check your version.